# Node View Permissions module prohibits list of nodes in Views module

Tags: 7, views

I created a custom node type called 'Video' in D7, and in it are three fields, 'YouTube ID', 'Video Title', and 'Video Description'. Basically, I have a template for this node type that puts the YouTube ID into the YouTube iframe to show the video. Not a problem. It works. These videos are for authenticated users only, and I can paste the url of one of the video pages on my site, and if I am logged in, I can see it.

**The problem isthat I cannot see my list of videos when logged in, *unless* I am logged in as admin**. The View to see the list of videos (/user-area/video) is accessible, but there is no list displayed unless I am logged in as admin.

It is something with the view and permissions, because I can see the video list page (/user-area/video ~ created by Views module), but without the list on it ... and I can see the video content page (/user-area/video/[video-id] ~ drupal node, themed by .tpl.php).

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

I figured out that it has something to do with the Node View Permissions module that I am using for the 'Video' node type. Although the setting in that module for the 'Video' node type is 'View any', Views must have a difficult time with that. I can still access the video content page, but not the list of video generated by the Views module. I have to figure this out. I updated the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem *was* the 'Node View Permissions' module not playing well with the 'Views' module (or the other way around). I removed the 'Node View Permissions' module and replaced it with the 'Restrict Node Page View' module. Did not work right away...had to rebuild permissions for the site. Problem fixed!